# Rescue ERRNO::EADDRINUSE in UDPSocket#bind

Tags: ruby, sockets, rescue

I'm trying to rescue the exception that ruby raises when you try to use the same address twice in a bind statement. The [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/UDPSocket.html) is not very helpful.
Here's what I want:

```
require 'socket'
s = UDPSocket.new(Socket::AF_INET)
begin
  s.bind address,port
rescue #Address_in_use => e
  #code
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rescue` without an explicit Exception class only rescues [StandardError](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/StandardError.html) and its subclasses. You should do the following:

```
rescue Errno::EADDRINUSE => ex
  #code
end
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried that and it raises a "name error" exception because ERRNO is not initialized, I don't know what or where is ERRNO. And yes I'm aware that rescuing Exception is a bad practice and that is exactly why I posted the question.

Comment: See the update. The error raised would have been Errno::EADDRINUSE and not ERRNO::EADDRINUSE. I had to reproduce this problem locally to find out the name of the Exception class. Please accept this answer now. I'm sure several rubyists would be wondering why my previous answer did not help you.

Comment: Thaks for the quick response, I tried that and now the error message is different, I updated the question so you can see what I'm talking about. Also, if you reproduced this error locally I assume you tested it. I'll try it in another machine to see what happens.

Comment: Can you post your whole file so that I can understand what you are trying to do? My spanish is not very good but from what I can gather, you don't have permission to bind to that port on that address. You can tell that it didn't enter your rescue block since the puts there was not printed. I think you now have a problem on a different line.

Comment: That would be problematic since this is a class in a rather large project but [here](http://tny.cz/89d2c8eb) is the relevant part.

Comment: By the way, the error: says "/mysocket.rb:20:in `write':" and the line 20 is the 'puts' statement.

Comment: Your current solution works in a SSCCE so it must be something else in my code but that is out of the scope of the question, I'll accept it and go back to check other options. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I reduced your code to this: http://tny.cz/260f1fc2 and it still works. Since the error is reported from `write`, it looks like you are having a problem with the send method.